Genus of the curve $x^a + 1 = y^b$ is always positive
I believe the statement in the question is true whenever $a > b \geq 2$, does anyone know of a way to prove this?
By homogenizing the equation we get
$$F:X^a+Z^a = Y^bZ^{a-b}.$$
Then by computing $\frac{\partial F}{\partial X}, \frac{\partial F}{\partial Y}, \frac{\partial F}{\partial Z}$, we see that $F$ has a singular point at $P = [0:1:0]$.
To compute the multiplicity of this singular point, we see that
$$F(X,1,Z) = X^a+Z^a-Z^{a-b} = 0$$
and so $P$ is a non-ordinary point of multiplicity $a-b$. This means that by the degree-genus formula, we should have
$$g(F) \leq \frac{(a-1)(a-2)}{2} - \frac{(a-b)(a-b-1)}{2}.$$
But this is not sufficient to guarantee that $g(F)$ is positive...

Hint. Use the Riemann-Hurwitz formula

@Mummytheturkey By your suggestion, I'm guessing we view $F$ as a degree $b$ covering of $\mathbb{P}^1$ and so by Riemann-Hurwitz we will have $$2g(F) = 2 - 2b + \deg R,$$ for some ramification divisor $R$, am I right?

Exactly, now work out what $R$ is explicitly.
